# regular expression validation errors

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem with regular expression validation, see If I put the validation in code behind like,

```
    [RegexValidator("[0-9 -]*"
        , MessageTemplateResourceName = "INVALID_PHONE"
        , MessageTemplateResourceType = typeof(ValidatioinErrors))]
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
    }
```

and if I give the value for phone as "080-244408" like this its working but if I give "080-2404408", that is one extra digit it shows error as "Invalid phone". What is the reason. can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: The regex as written will match both of your examples fine, so you really need to provide more detail about the surrounding code/framework.

Comment: why not limit the textbox's max length?

Comment: hi amber and bahamut thanks for ur instant response, how can I limit the textbox's length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like a problem with your regex. You need to give more information on this. Something else might be wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks Amber, Bahamut and latest Version...I got the solution, the mistake is mine only, I just used the stringlength validator before regex, and I limit the length from 1 to 10, actually i was trying with >10 chars, finally I fixed it....its working fine....thanks alot for ur guidance