# regular expression for indian phone number

Tags: c#, regex, phone-number

am looking for the regular expression of indian phone number

the regular expression should allow all the following formats.

for landline no

```
0802404408
080-2404408
+91802404408
+91-802404408
```

for mobile no

```
8147708287
08147708287
+918147708287
+91-8147708287
```

can anyone help me, thanks in advance

my code is

```
[RegexValidator("[0-9 -]*"
, MessageTemplateResourceName = "INVALID_PHONE"
, MessageTemplateResourceType = typeof(ValidatioinErrors))]
public string Phone
{
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
}

public bool IsValid()
    {
        return Validation.Validate<Class_name>(this).IsValid;
    }

    public ValidationResults ValResults
    {
        get
        {
            return Validation.Validate<Class_name>(this);
        }
    }
```

for this validation thing I just referred

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;
```

in my namespace, in the UI part the expression is working fine, but in the code behind as above, it shows "Invalid Phone number", if I give value as 080-2404408

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a site where others do your work for you. Further, for those not familiar with Indian numbers, you need to explain further what the rules are. How many digits, what digits are specifically required.

Comment: thanks Phrogz, I tried the simple expression for number format as "[0-9 -]*", it seems no error right, but when I use this expression in code behind(in my business object) and if I put the value as "080-2404408" the condition is not satisfied and it shows error. but if I use this in the design part it works fine, I tried in the web n I found only for the landline format or mobile, but I need to allow them both, thats what am asking....sorry to disturb you here.

Comment: @Shanish, your regex `[0-9 -]*` will match "080-2404408". If you get an error for that, the problem is somewhere else. You already [got this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9495246/626273)!

Comment: @Stema of course, the problem is am still getting the error, and when I check that question thread, showed that the question is closed, thats what am asking here again

Comment: @Shanish, that question is not closed, you just need to provide more information. And as we already clarified, the problem is not in the regex, so show the code where you are using the regex and where its not working.

Comment: sorry stema,anubhava,arshwarsi, and phrogz. the mistake is mine only, I just limited the string length upto 10 characters and was trying to add more than 10 chars, finally I fixed....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
^\+?[0-9-]+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?308bc)

The important parts are the anchors `^` and `$` for the start and the end of the string. I added also `\+?` at the start, to match an optional `+`. The `+` needs to be escaped since it is a special character in regex, the `?` after it makes it optional.

Of course this is a very simple pattern, be aware that e.g. "-----" would also be valid.

Comment: thanks for ur response stema, when I try your expression it shows error that the "+" is unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @Shanish maybe you need double escaping? Try `^\\+?[0-9-]+$`. you don't tell us your language, maybe you can use a raw/verbatim string to avoid the double escaping.

Comment: thanks stema for your kind response, see am checking the phone no format in both the UI part as well as in the codebehind, for this cb am using the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators dll, when I give the phone no value as 080-244408 or 0802404408 it shows no error, but when i give 080-2404408(1 extra char than previous) its shows invalid phone no, am still facing this, see am just a beginner, am using this in c#.net

Comment: Edit your **code** into the question (only the important parts, that we can see what you are doing!). In comments its not good to read and less people will see it.

Comment: thanks stema, I got the solution, the mistake is mine only, I just used the stringlength validator before regex, and I limit the length from 1 to 10, actually i was trying to with >10 chars, finally I fixed it....its working fine.....thanks alot for ur guidance and kind response

Answer (score 2):

For the examples provided following RegEx works:

```
/^(?:\+91(?:-)?|0\d{2,4}-|0|)\d{7,10}$/
```

Comment: time to let him know yet ?

Comment: @shanish: Your question title is checking Indian phone numbers and your accepted answer will also allow `+44` or `+92` country codes.

Answer (score 0):

import re
mystr = """
8147708287
08147708287
+918147708287
+91-8147708287
"""

print(re.findall(r'\b91-*\d{10}',mystr))

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. Care to explain?