# phone number validation that accept only + and - signs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have to write the Regular expression that accept two signs only + and - and can be of any no. of digit but + should be the first sign if it is there

Comment: In which language you want? your tags are confusing?

Comment: i need to write it in asp.net

Comment: Can you provide us some examples of "good" and "bad" values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the following:

- `+` may only be at the beginning of the number
- `-` should not be

  - at the beginning or end of the number
  - consecutively repeated

You could try this regular expression:

```
^\+?(?:[\d]+\-)*[\d]+$
```

Passes the following string examples:

- +12-34-5678-90
- 12-345-678-90
- 1234567890

Fails the following string examples:

- ++12-34-5678-90
- 12+34-5678-90
- 12-34-5678-90-
- 12--34-5678-90

**EDIT**

As @Alovchin pointed out, the OP expressed the need to allow for dots (`.`) as well in the numbers in [one of the answer comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427415/phone-number-validation-that-accept-only-and-signs/25427529#comment39668359_25427529). Although this requirement does not reflect in the question I am going to add it here just-in-case.

If the requirement is to allow for dots (`.`) as well then the above regex will need to be updated to the following.

```
^\+?(?:[\d]+[\-\.])*[\d]+$
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And if you need to match points (`.`), you will need to correct this regex: `^\+?(?:[\d]+[\-\.])*[\d]+$`

Comment: @Alovchin the OP's request was for a regex that needed to match `+`, `-` and numbers only. Depending on the requirement the regex may change drastically.

Comment: OP mentioned dots in a comment below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427415/phone-number-validation-that-accept-only-and-signs/25427529#comment39668359_25427529

Comment: @Alovchin I would not have known that unless the comment was in the question itself. OP should seriously consider updating the question as per the requirement. I'll update my answer anyway.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I just mentioned this in the comment because I have seen the OP's "new" requirement. The original question is rather incorrect anyway.

Comment: @Alovchin I agree. The original question is vague enough to answer correctly. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
^\+?[0-9-]+$
```

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596925/regular-expression-for-indian-phone-number) This is for indian numbers.

Answer (score 0):

<s>In **C#** try this one:</s>

```
^\+?(?![\-\.])[\d\-\.]+(?<![\-\.])$
```

There's a better answer by **Tanzeel Kazi**.

Comment: so it will validate no. like  77690-79048 and +997841235

Comment: It will also test positive for `"herpderpt+997841235derpderp"`.

Comment: @canon, no, it won't.

Comment: @Alovchin Try `Regex.IsMatch("herpderpt+997841235derpderp", @"\+?[\d\-]+")`. You didn't specify `^` and `$` so it tests positive for substrings.

Comment: @Alovchin: It will because you are not anchoring your regular expression to the start and end of the string. Try it here: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=999d5075-90c0-4b42-9a75-93d3f6a86ce2

Comment: @canon Ah, you mean it will match inside the string? Yes, I did it intentionally if the guy needs to parse phone numbers from one long string. He didn't specify where he needs it.

Comment: i need it alows only three signs i.e. 
1. + if it then it should be the first digit
2. - shouldn't be the first and last character and shouldn't appear immediately after +, if + is present.
3. . (dot) is also allowed

Comment: @user3395635 It would be great if you provide some more details on how you are going to use it. Because if you're parsing a single string like `+564879 489-546-565 +8954423` etc., you will be good with this regex. But if you are parsing separate lines, you will need to add the line start (`^`) and line end (`$`) markers in order to not match something like _canon_ mentioned.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but there is a better answer by _Tanzeel Kazi_.